# (Hypothetical Scenario) How quickly the temperatures would rise if say 300Gt $\rm CH_4$ were released in less than one day( or within hours)?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science, estimation, climate-science

Yes, I know sounds a bit dumb but I wondered how quickly the temperatures would rise in this extremely unlikely scenario, how long it would take (days, weeks).

I'm asking this because sometimes I worry, not just because of hydrates but also in case of some massive accident ( since in a few decades we could start carbon capture and storage and some nations are also interested in exploring hydrates as fuel).

I asked this question on Reddit last week, but I never got any answers so I decided to ask here, since it's a more science-focused website, also I don't know much about science in general so, sorry if the question sounds weird.

Comment: I don't have the math on hand, but one observation I can make is that it the radioactive cloud from the Fukushima incident took 3 days to cross the Pacific ocean.  I think this provides a reasonable bound on how fast a "fast" release has to be.  Transient effects less than a week are going to be inherently limited by the percent of the globe covered by the CH4 dump.

Comment: As a related question: what temperature are you talking about measuring?  The Earth consists of several compartment, regions which gain and release heat at different speeds.  The atmospheric temperatures can rise and fall rather rapidly.  Sea temperatures move much more slowly because there's a gargantuan mass of water behind them.  Many climate change scientists follow the sea temperature numbers because they have so much more inertia behind them.  Which temperatures were you interested in?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know it's hard to calculate stuff like this, I made that quention because I read this old paper: https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/clim/25/24/jcli-d-11-00533.1.xml and wondered how fast the air temperatures would rise.